# ortools: best practice for partial assignments

Tags: or-tools

I would like to constrain my VRP with partial assignments. Given a list of stops `assigned_stops` and a vehicle id I would like to find solutions such that all stops in the list are serviced by the given vehicle and in the given order.

For example, if I want to assign all stops in a list `assigned_stops` to the vehicle with index 5 I use the following code (Python):

```
vehicle_ix = 5
for stop1, stop2 in zipper(assigned_stops):
  ix1 = stops.index(stop1)
  ix2 = stops.index(stop2)
  cpsolver.Add(routing_model.VehicleVar(ix1) == vehicle_ix)
  cpsolver.Add(routing_model.VehicleVar(ix2) == vehicle_ix)
  cpsolver.Add(stop_sequence_dimension.CumulVar(ix1) < stop_sequence_dimension.CumulVar(ix2))
```

It works. But I am only enforcing pair-wise inequalities for successive `ix1`, `ix2`. Would it help the solver if I added all possible inequality constraints?